# Loop in Perl - with LWP::UserAgent

Tags: perl, loops, lwp-useragent

Here the code that has needs to be build in loop - to make USER-Agent to iterate
over a bunch of targets.

```
 for my $i (1..10000) {
     my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET =>
sprintf("http://www.example.com,%d", $i));
```

Is this the correct way to iterate? I love to hear from you ... to get a
starting-point...

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` on your loop, and your `sprintf` won't make a valid URL (I'm guessing you want a / there instead of a comma.) But otherwise it should work fine.

Comment: Hello Friedo - many thanks for the quick reply! How - does Sprintf does not fit? Here i can provide some "more help for getting the target!" -btw see three detail page:
http://www.schulministerium.nrw.de/BP/SchuleSuchen?action=261.2855969084779&SchulAdresseMapDO=116191
http://www.schulministerium.nrw.de/BP/SchuleSuchen?action=261.2855969084779&SchulAdresseMapDO=116270
http://www.schulministerium.nrw.de/BP/SchuleSuchen?action=261.2855969084779&SchulAdresseMapDO=188268
btw: we can loop over the results - with a iteration -

Comment: Friedo - should this be named other - sprintf("http://www.example.com,%d", $i)); without the comma!?Note i have many many pages that have results - and many not: so i have to make a iteration on a wide  range - parse all and throw away all those without a results /(By the way: are those pages such with 500er errors!? )

Comment: Did you create yourself a sockpuppet account? See http://stackoverflow.com/users/477580/thebutcher

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, you may want to use `WWW::Mechanize` instead, which is a handy sub-class for the LWP::Module. For what you want to do the code could look like this:

```
foreach my $i (1..1000)
{
   #$mech is a object for WWW::Mechanize
   $mech->get("http://yourtarget.com/whateveryouwant"); 
}
```

Then you can sort the results e.g. by response code (404 - Not Found, 200 - OK...) by checking `$mech->status()`

Comment: hello Cyber-Guard Design, Many thanks for your answer. Mecha seems to be more handy and appropiate. I will have a closer look at the Mecha-Man-Pages @ CPAN. Again: Mille Grazie - great board here. Keep up the great work... ;-)

Comment: Hi, glad I could help. Definitely check out the man pages, it is literally the most comprehensive guide for the module... And when it comes to website processing with perl, it doesn't get better than WWW::Mechanize, so easy to use and flexible!